# FFTW gives wrong results in comparison to MATLAB

Tags: c++, matlab, signal-processing, fftw

After analysing some signal data, I do some resynthesis. For analysing e.g. a wav-file I use CUDA-CUFFT for 1D-complex-FFT-transformation, after some signal processing operations (cutting pieces of signals,...) I do an IFFT-tranformation using FFTWF (FFTW=for float type).

On the CUDA-side I verified the FFT-transformation with MATLAB and get almost the same results (due to round-off errors it's not exactyl the same). After cutting the signal and performin the FFTShift-operation the signals seem to be almost equal.
[image: plot showing the difference of the magnitudes of the matlab values with my values after cutting the signal and performin the fftshift operation]

But after the IFFT-operation I get complete different results (directly after the IFFT-operation I reverse the output, which I also do in MATLAB -> and finally I save the FFTW-output to a binary file for comparison)

P.S:(for additional information. after flipping the output I norm the results with `sqrtf(FFTLEN);` (on the CUDA-site I norm the output with `1/sqrtf(FFTLEN)`

[image: magnitude difference plot after the IFFT operation and performing the flipud/reverse in MATLAB and in my program]

For the IFFT-transformation with FFTW I use the following syntax in the documentation:
http://www.fftw.org/doc/Complex-One_002dDimensional-DFTs.html
But instead of using the fftw_complex type I use the C++-complex-type and cast it to fftw_complex-type. The operation sign is `FFTW_BACKWARD` beacuse I use `CUFFT_FORAWRD` on the CUDA-site:

```
fftwf_plan localFFTPlan;
localFFTPlan = fftwf_plan_dft_1d((int)sFFTParams.uFFTLength, reinterpret_cast<fftwf_complex*>(&tFFTraw[0]), reinterpret_cast<fftwf_complex*>(&tFFTin[0]), FFTW_BACKWARD, FFTW_MEASURE);
fftwf_execute(localFFTPlan);
fftwf_destroy_plan(localFFTPlan);
```

In MATLAB the same operation is performed like this:

```
flipud(ifft(fftshift(st))
```

Can anyone help me, why the results get wrong directyl after the IFFT-transformation(as shown above, before the operation everything is fine)?

**EDIT**
the array allocation looks like the following statement:
    TFFTContainer tFFTin(sFFTParams.uFFTLength, gComplexZero);

Comment: Can you show the code where `tFFTraw` and `tFFTin` are declared/allocated ?

Comment: For one thing FFTW's FFT is not normalized, ie. round-trip (forward then backward) transform scales the signal by N, whereas Matlab's FFT is normalized (which means round trip does not change the signal's scale).

Comment: @PaulR I allocate the containers like this: TFFTContainer tfftraw(FFTLEN, zeroComplexType); the same is for tFFTin;TFFTContainer is a typedef for a vector of the C++ complex-type, and zeroComplexType is a zero initialized global)

Comment: @SleuthEye Thanks, that will solve one problem, but where do the strange values come?

Comment: Perhaps with a small input/output sample instead of the screenshot where the imaginary parts are obscured, and where we have to guess which is `ixbnorm`/`hybnorm` and whether they're row or column data, along with why you feel there are _strange_ values, we could provide a more complete explanation.

Comment: @SleuthEye you were right with the scaling with N  solved the problem (there was another "error, where I cleared the inpu tbuffer) :)

Comment: Perhaps someone can provide an answer if the problem is now solved (although I'm sure the scale-by-N is a duplicate of some fftw question somewhere).  I'm removing the CUDA tag since neither the question nor the answer (it seems) have anything significant to do with CUDA.

Comment: Shameless plug. Same issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571641/diferences-between-dft-and-fft-magnitude-results/30591537#30591537) with answer.

Comment: @AviGinsburg What do you mean with 'shameless plug'->google translator (English->German) gives me something like 'shameless surreptitious advertising' (because I didn't know the meaning of the word 'plug' in combination with 'shameless'?
If you mean a duplicate, then the thing was that I searched for IFFTW-MATLAB-FFT and not for the tags OpenCV so I haven't seen the linked question. But I'm sorry for the possible duplicate

Comment: @mbed_dev No, it was meant as disclosure in that I wrote the answer that I linked to. While the underlying issue is the same, I did not flag this as duplicate, as searching for the different contexts won't necessarily come up with the same results.

Comment: @AviGinsburg Oh, I see. Thanks for your answer for the problem anyway.